# Can Gmail be set to do send/receive email rather than synching

Tags: applications, sync, gmail

I seldom use my cell phone for emailing but want to be able to do so occasionally. I know how to add non-Gmail email accounts to the Gmail app, but I want to set sync to "never" for them so that my battery isn't continually being sucked unnecessarily. But I can't figure out how to tell Gmail to do a receive on those few occasions that I need to check email on the phone. Is there a way? Or do I need to find a different email app?